# cant connect to repositories in collabnet

Tags: eclipse, repository, collabnet

I have set up collabnet subversion edge server and I have installed collabnet plugin for eclipse . The problem I have encountered is that I can't connect to my repositories . When I try to import a project to the server , I am getting such an error:

svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://localhost/viewvc/rep/android'
svn: 'http://localhost/viewvc/rep/android' path not found

What can I do to fix that error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `http://localhost/svn/rep/android` instead of `http://localhost/viewvc/rep/android`

The viewvc url is only for viewing the repo contents in the browser via viewvc